# python regex failing to find all matches

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

My regex is failing to capture all groups when I run in python, and I'm at a loss why...

I'm trying to pull out the sequences of numbers.

```py
import re

my_string = '467..114..'
re.search(r'(?:(\d+)(?:\.*))*',my_string).groups()
# outputs ('114',)
```

I expect this to get the two groups, '467', and '114'.

To explain the expression (or what I'm thinking for it):

1. I want to capture a series of digits, needs to have at least one but can have many - `(\d+)`
2. This will be followed by zero or more periods/dots, which I don't want to capture - `(?:\.*)`
3. This pattern of digits followed by dots could repeat, so the two above are wrapped together in another non-capturing group that can repeat 0-or-more times.

I've gotten things to pull out either the first or second set of digits, but struggling to get both at once...

I do know I could use `re.findall()` to just get the numbers, but I want the span and I want to know why it isn't working...

Edit:

I've found that `re.finditer()` does indeed return Match objects, not just the list of strings like `re.findall()`. That seems like a reasonable way for me to actually go, but still curious about how to get it to work with search, which I feel like should be possible...

Comment: A much simpler expression outputs what you asked for: **print(re.findall(r'\d+', '467..114..'))** That, unless you provide a group of digits in your example you don't want to be captured.

Comment: yes, I did find that `re.findall()` does give the list of the numbers, but i also want to know the start/end location - the span associated with the matches. And while I could use findall to find the matches, and then a string find to get the starting index, I'm also confused about why the search is failing in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work in [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) because you have a repeated capture group, which will only return the last match (See for example [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) for an explanation) and it won't work if you remove the repeat, since `search` only returns the first match (from the manual):

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match

For your use case, you can use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), but you still need to remove the repeat on the outer group or you will match the entire string i.e. `re.finditer(r'(?:(\d+)(?:\.*))',my_string)`

Note that with the use of `finditer`, the `(?:\.*)` is redundant since it will match an empty string. If you want to enforce that the digits are followed by a `.`, you need to change that to `(?:\.+)`, otherwise, just remove it and you can simply use `\d+`. Either way, you can also remove most of the groups.

So, to match the numbers with the dots, you can do:

```
[m for m in re.finditer(r'\d+\.+',my_string)]
```

And you will get

```
[
 <re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='467..'>,
 <re.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='114..'>
]
```

Or to match only the numbers:

```
[m for m in re.finditer(r'\d+',my_string)]
```

Output:

```
[
 <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='467'>,
 <re.Match object; span=(5, 8), match='114'>
]
```

If you might have other numbers in the string and you only want to match the numbers followed by dots, either match them as above or use a lookahead to assert they are there:

```
[m for m in re.finditer(r'\d+(?=\.)',my_string)]
```

Output:

```
[
 <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='467'>,
 <re.Match object; span=(5, 8), match='114'>
]
```

Comment: @scotscotmcc Note that if you really only want the digits in your match, you can use a lookahead for the dots instead of a non-capturing group. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `list(re.finditer(pattern, string))`?

This will return a list of re.Match objects containing all of the matches.

The reason why you are only getting the first match is because `re.search` only returns the first match. See [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

(Note: I wanted to add this as a comment but don't have the reputation to comment)

Comment: I support this one. Poked a bit and it worked out. Still not sure, what's wrong with **re.search(...)**

Comment: With **r'\d+'** pattern it does not return a thing.

Comment: Actually you'll note that OP is getting the *last* match, not the first